# Play! Framework. How to get a subset of the fields in a JPA object and process it in a template

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to retrieve only a subset of the properties of my JPA object to use in my Play! template.

this is in my controller Application:

```
public static List<Object> all2D() {
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("defaultPersistenceUnit");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    TypedQuery<Object> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT title, unitPrice FROM Item i", Object.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

This is the code I earlier used in order to get every fields out of my JPA object, called Item

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    get_itemz();       
});

var get_itemz = function() {       
    $.ajax({
        url: '@routes.Application.getJson()',
        processData:false,
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend:function(jqXHR, settings){                   
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");                 
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                 
            process_itemz(data);   
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){                
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR,textStatus){                   
        }   
    });
};

var process_itemz = function(itemz){      
    var contentDiv=$("div#content");
    contentDiv.append("<ul>");            
    $.each(itemz,function(i,item){
        contentDiv.append("<li>" + item.name + "</li>");
    });
    contentDiv.append("</ul>");                 
};
</script>
```

How could i transform the javascript in order to process the list of Objects and print the name and unitPrice?

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for Javascript for this, but if Javascript is not mandatory, an alternative using the scala.html could be roughly as follows.

Since you already have your List generated just pass that to your template instead.

```
@(objects: List[Object])
```

Then since you simply want to print the name and unit price simply traverse the list and output your fields.

```
@for(event <- eventsList){
     object.name object.unitPrice    
}
```

You can use the for loop in a table as well, but this should accomplish more or less what it appears you would like to do to simply reference elements in your template.